# convert json string to java string array

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I am getting a json string as ["A","B","C","D","E"] in serlvet controller.

I want to convert this string into a Java string array.  The Json string also includes [].

output should be a Java String array:

```
arr[0] = A
arr[1] = B
```

and so on. Could you please suggest a parsing solution?

Answer (score 3):

Using a stream you could convert it like so:

```
String s = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"D\",\"E\"]";
String[] arr = Arrays.stream(s.substring(1, s.length()-1).split(","))
                .map(e -> e.replaceAll("\"", ""))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

You could also use a JSON library (which might be the prefered way). For example using Jackson:

```
String s = "[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"D\",\"E\"]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String[] arr = mapper.readValue(s, String[].class);
```

Comment: Parsing JSON on your is risky in terms of security (especially in a web environment). Just use one of the well-known JSON libraries as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), etc.

Comment: Right @jannis, added an example with jackson

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> jsonStringToArray(String jsonString) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }

    return stringArray;
}
```